# JQuery Slider and Textbox within asp repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm attempting to create a list of items within a repeater. Each item containing a percentage slider with a textbox. I want the textbox and corresponding slider to be linked so the user has 2 methods of input.

The functionality is working in a sense, however the functions are currently based over the class name and not the ID which results in a single slider updating all textboxes within the repeater and vice-versa.

Any suggestions on how to link the pairs together correctly within the repeater?

Many Thanks :-)

JS

```
<script>
    $(function () {     
        $(".compDiscSlider").slider({
            value: 0,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            animate: true,
            step: 0.25,
            min: 0.00,
            max: 100.00,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $(".compDiscTB").val(ui.value + "%");
            }
        });
        $(".compDiscTB").change(function () {
            $(".compDiscSlider").slider("value", parseFloat(this.value));
        });
    });
</script>
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptComponents" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnItemDataBound="rptComponents_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>  
        <td data-title="Discount">  
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhDiscountPricing" runat="server">
                <div id="compDiscSlider" class=compDiscSlider style="width:260px; margin:15px"></div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="compDiscTB" runat="server" CssClass="compDiscTB"></asp:TextBox> 
             </asp:PlaceHolder>
         </td>  
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what do you mean by "link". Do you mean something like "if user updates one, another gets updated, and vice versa"?

Comment: Hi Andrei. Thanks for responding and apologies for being unclear. Yes, I did mean the items to update each other,  I had some success with:  
$(this).next().val(ui.value + "%");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 slide: function (event, ui) {
            this.next('input').val(ui.value + "%");
        }
```

Grab the next input by using JQuery .next('input') call. This is probably not exactly right, but should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. I had some success with: $(this).next().val(ui.value + "%");